# How to mock function in service called by another method in the service called by the controller

Tags: jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

I'm trying to test my controller function which is:

```
import { InstalledPackages } from '../parser/parser.service';
import {
  getOutdatedPackages,
  InstalledPackageStatus,
} from './version-control.service';

interface OutdatedPackages {
  dependencies: InstalledPackageStatus[];
  devDependencies: InstalledPackageStatus[];
}

export async function getPackagesUpdatesToNotify(
  packages: InstalledPackages,
  type = 'package.json',
): Promise<OutdatedPackages> {
  return getOutdatedPackages(packages.dependencies, type);
}
```

And having my service like this:

```
import { fetch } from "../common/http.service";

export async function getLastPackageVersion(
  packageName: string
): Promise<VersionType> {
  const url = `https://registry.npmjs.org/-/package/${packageName}/dist-tags`;
  return await (<Promise<VersionType>>fetch(url));
}

export async function getOutdatedPackages(
  installedPackages: PackagesVersion,
  type: string
): Promise<InstalledPackageStatus[]> {
  return Promise.all(
    Object.keys(installedPackages).map(async (packageName) =>
      getLastPackageVersion(packageName)
    )
  );
}
```

I've already tried both solutions:

```
import * as myService from './my.service';

it('my test', async () => {
  const getLastPackageVersionSpy = jest.spyOn(myService, 'getLastPackageVersion').mockReturnValue(
    Promise.resolve(42),

    await getPackagesUpdatesToNotify(packages, type)
});
```

and

```
import { getLastPackageVersion } from './my.service';
import { getPackagesUpdatesToNotify } from './version-control.controller';

jest.mock('./myse.service', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('./myse.service'),
  getLastPackageVersion: jest.fn(),
}));

it('my test', async () => {
  (getLastPackageVersion as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(
    Promise.resolve(42),
  );

  await getPackagesUpdatesToNotify(packages, type)
});
```

But the original function is always called instead of the mocked one.

How to mock the getLastPackageVersion method.
I'm trying to avoid using tools like rewire if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Move the `getLastPackageVersion` to different file, import it in the `my.service` and then mock it.

`my.service`:

```js
import { fetch } from "../common/http.service";
import { getLastPackageVersion } from '../last-package-version'; 

export async function getOutdatedPackages(
  installedPackages: PackagesVersion,
  type: string
): Promise<InstalledPackageStatus[]> {
  return Promise.all(
    Object.keys(installedPackages).map(async (packageName) =>
      getLastPackageVersion(packageName)
    )
  );
}
```

```js
import * as lastPackageVersion from '../last-package-version';

it('my test', async () => {
  const getLastPackageVersionSpy = jest.spyOn(lastPackageVersion, 'getLastPackageVersion').mockResolvedValue(42);

 await getPackagesUpdatesToNotify(packages, type)
});
```

`getOutdatedPackages` is in the same file as the `getLastPackageVersion` so it cannot be mocked. In your case the `getOutdatedPackages` is still using the original `getLastPackageVersion` method.